# SQL select from multiple tables and applying different criteria in one of them

Tags: sql, select

SQL select from multiple tables and applying different criteria in one of them

First table:

```
 Student Name | Student ID
 --------------------------
   John Smith | 1
Marry Johnson | 2
```

Second table:

```
Student ID | Year | Enrollment date
-----------------------------------
         1 | 2013 | 2013-10-01
         1 | 2014 | 2014-02-01
         2 | 2013 | 2013-10-01
         2 | 2014 | 2014-02-01
```

Third table:

```
Student ID | Year | Class
---------------------------
         1 | 2013 | Math
         1 | 2013 | Spanish
         1 | 2013 | Art
         1 | 2014 | French
         2 | 2014 | Math
         2 | 2013 | Spanish
         2 | 2014 | Literature
         2 | 2014 | French
         2 | 2014 | Art
```

How can I get list of students (`Name` from `Table 1` + `Year` & `Enrollment date` from `Table 2`) which took `Math` and `Art` classes in the same year?

```
 Student Name | Year | Enrollment date
 -------------------------------------
   John Smith | 2013 | 2013-10-01
Marry Johnson | 2014 | 2014-02-01
```

Comment: which database - oracle, mysql, sql server ?

Comment: Didn't John Smith take math on 2013 and Art on 2014? that contradict your request because those wasn't on same year!

Comment: @ericpap I think what he is wanting is that Marry and John took math the same year as each other and art the same year as each other so return both of them.

Comment: @ericpap - I guess he probably means who took math in the same year, who took art in the same year etc...

Comment: second table makes no sense with your results.  Why the earlier date for one student and the later date for the other?

Comment: @Borat - Actually it's DB2 database

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.studentName, d.EnrollmentDate 
From firstTable s
   join thirdTable m 
       on m.StudentId = s.studentId
           and m.class = 'Math'
   join thirdTable 
       on a.StudentId = s.studentId
          and a.year = m.year              -- ensure that art is in same year as math
          and a.class = 'Art'
   join secondTable d
       on d.studentId = s.studentId
          and d.Year = m.year
```

or, if this is a recent release of SQL Server 
(which supports dynamic resultsets based on values clause)
 - this also addresses problem of adding arbitrary number of additional classes

```
Select s.studentName, d.EnrollmentDate 
From firstTable s
   join secondTable d
       on d.studentId = s.studentId
          and d.Year = m.year 
Where Not exists 
    (Select * From (values ('Math'), ('Art')) c(class)
     where Not exists
         (Select * from thirdTable
          Where studentId = s.studentId
              and year = d.Year
              and class = c.class))
```

syntactically, thios reads as:

*Show me the students where there is **not** a class (in the class list provided), that they did **not** enroll in in the same year*

Comment: I was thinking of a similar solution, and I think this will work.  I'm curious to know, however, what you would suggest if he needed to include a third (or fourth, or tenth) class in the list. Adding more JOINs would eventually become prohibitive ...

Comment: I am just wondering how the second example could be expanded if I would like to add second criteria in third table for example not only "Class" but also "Level" (as a separate column)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ft.student_name, st.Year, st.Enrollment_date from first_table ft
inner join second_table st on(ft.student_id = st.student_id) 
inner join third_table tt 
on(ft.student_id = tt.student_id and tt.class = 'Art')
inner join third_table tt1 
on(ft.student_id = tt1.student_id and tt1.class = 'Math'
 and tt.year = tt1.year) where tt.year = st.year
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9e5e/1/0

Comment: In your case there are no matches as the question you are asking is contradictory to the data so I have assumed that it is typo.

Answer (score 0):

If my comment is right and what you are wanting is to get students who took classes together, then this will work to get you a list.  However, I'm still not certain how you are linking to the enrollment date table.

```
select t1a.[student name] as Student1, t1b.[student name] as Student2 from
thirdtable t3a 
inner join thirdtable t3b on t3a.[Student ID]<t3b.[Student ID]
inner join firsttable t1a on t3a.[Student ID] = t1a.[Student ID]
inner join firsttable t1b on t1b.[Student ID] = t3b.[Student ID]
where t3a.class = t3b.class and t3a.year = t3b.year and t3a.class  in ('Art','Math')
group by t1a.[student name], t1b.[student name]
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Deciding whether to use a WHERE clause or a JOIN can sometimes be tricky.  If you're using a version of SQL that allows INTERSECT, you have even more options.  I would try:

```
 select t1.name, t2.year, t2.enrollment_date
 from table_1 t1 join table_2 t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id and t1.year = t2.year
 join (
      select student_id, year from t3 where class = 'Math'
      intersect
      select student_id, year from t3 where class = 'Art'
      ) fred on t1.student_id = fred.student_id and t1.year=fred.year
```

The inner select is pretty versatile here; you could add plenty of other classes if you wished.  If INTERSECT doesn't work in your flavor, the joins others recommended will work.  Still, I recommend doing them on the t3 table alone as a subselect then joining the results to table 1 and table 2 later as it saves some messiness:

```
 select t1.name, t2.year, t2.enrollment_date
 from table_1 t1 join table_2 t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id and t1.year = t2.year
 join (
      select t3_math.student_id, t3_math.year from table_3 t3_math
           join table_3 t3_art on t3_math.id = t3_art.id and t3_math.year = t3_art.year
           where t3_art.class = 'Art' and t3_math.class = 'Math'
      ) fred on t1.student_id = fred.student_id and t1.year=fred.year
```